# Getting SCRIPT5009: 'id' is undefined in Internet Explore IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a very simple script(setUser) which is called on click of a button.This script is working fine in chrome but in IE 11 i am getting a console error.
Another weird thing is i am getting that error only when dev tool is open.It works fine if devtool is not open.

Error is :- 
SCRIPT5009: 'id' is undefined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setUser(eventType){
            console.log(eventType);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="vish" onclick="setUser(id)" style="height:40px;width:200px">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Simple Workaround for this is to declare a 
var id; just below the script.But i need the proper documented reason why this doesnot work in ie11 but same works in chrome.And is a better solution than what i tried

Workaround :- by adding var id at the top

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var id;
        function setUser(eventType){
            console.log(eventType);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="vish" onclick="setUser(id)" style="height:40px;width:200px">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

expected :-
when dev tool is open in ie11 and when we click the button we should get the console log as "vish"

actual result :- 
SCRIPT5009: 'id' is undefined js error

Comment: does `this.id` work? Otherwise you could do a JavaScript workaround.

Comment: Good reason to not put onclick attributes inside the HTML. Use `.addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) { ... }`.  The you can get the id as `event.target.id` or `event.target.getAttribute("id");` so you do not need a seperate variable to exist. Trying to figure out why it works in chrome but not IE11.

Comment: @AnisR. yes this.id works thanks.But is this is a known issue is there any documentation somewhere.Looks like a common issue

Comment: @Shilly,yes thanks for the feedback but i wanted to know what is the reason behind this or any doc mentione about this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is simply undefined, as the error message says. If you declare it, the error is gone, but it won't behave like you expected. If you declare it, it exists with value undefined. You probably wanted

```
onclick="setUser(this.id)"
```

`this.id` means the button context, while simply `id` tries to find it in global context. In case of your error, `id` is not **declared**, whereas

```
var id; // or var id=undefined;
```

declares it, and leaves it undefined, so the browser at least knows it is a variable. By saying *id is undefined* Explorer means it is not declared.

I believe the reason is that the browser searches for variables **and** named elements (referenced by name or id attribute; this is not standard, but browsers do it), which actually doesn't exist in global context and are looked up by reference and Explorer obviously can't handle this situation. If it is declared as *var*, javascript knows it is not a named element reference.

Example below shows the non-standard behaviour: it should end with error *test is not defined* (it really is not), but browsers say *hello*.

```
<input id="test" value="hello">
<script>
  alert(test.value);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of it not working in IE11 is because you do not specify a doctype for the HTML document in the block of code that threw the error.

If I add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the start of the HTML, as in the workaround you show; it works in IE11 as well for me, without adding the var id;

The exact reason is unknown to me, but without the doctype, IE will run the page in quirks mode. And that seems to mess up the determination of the function scope when the browser tries to parse `onclick="setUser(id)"` into valid JS code.

This would not happen if the doctype is correct and the page can hence be run in the correct mode.
This would also no happen if the browsers HTML engine did not have to parse the HTML string `setUser(id)` into valid JS code before it can be used. Hence it's not a common issue anymore since the standard these days is to not use inline event handler attributes on HTML tags.

So prefer explicit event binding with javascript when possible to not run into issues like this, where a totally unrelated part, the doctype, messes up your code.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> is present i missed it while adding

Comment: still i see the issue

Comment: That's what did it for me. Without the doctype, I get `SCRIPT5009: 'id' is undefined` every time. With the doctype, everything works in IE11 if I open the console first before pressing 'allow scripts'. If I open the console after, sometimes I get an error again. I did have to clear the cache every time to switch between the versions. So it's clearly related to how the function scope gets resolved in IE11 in HTML5 mode vs in other modes. Which is then related to how IE11 is coded. Hence the issue does not exist in Chrome.

Comment: Nice, but i am shocked this error doesnot appear if you close the dev tool of ie11

Comment: IE11 is weird when it comes to debugging. I have similar issues with other code that uses console methods. Haven't figured it out completely, but it seems to me as if the console does not exist in IE11 if F12 dev tools are not open. Other pieces of the IE11 dev tools also do not work as expected. I'll be glad when my company can switch to edge and drop IE11 support.

Comment: same here big headache of maintaining ie 11

Answer (score 0):

Using `onclick="setUser(this.id)"` should work.

However, a cleaner workaround would be to do all the `onclick` handling in JavaScript:

```js
onload = function() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log(this.id);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="vish" style="height:40px;width:200px">Click Me</button>
    <button id="vish2" style="height:40px;width:200px">Click Me 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```